# How to use Random and count clicks on Android app

Tags: java, android, xml, random

I'm making this app that when you press like or dislike
it will count the number and save it.
that is not that hard but here's the problem
I need the names to be chosen randomly and the likes and dislikes to be saved for each randomly chosen name separately but every time i press like or dislike Random generates a new number and stores likes or dislikes on the new randomly chosen name

I'm posting all my code below and for this example i only have three names and fixed numbers on the arrays so that you can easily check the problem yourselves

MainActivity java

```
package gr.com.plaza.stackoverflowquestion;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.content.Intent;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Second question = new Second();

    TextView boyname = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.boy);
    boyname.setText(question.getboyname());
    TextView girlname = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.girl);
    girlname.setText(question.getgirlname());
}
public void yesclick(View v){
    Intent click = new Intent(this, SecondActivity.class);

    String boyname = ((TextView)findViewById(R.id.boy)).getText().toString();
    click.putExtra("boyname", boyname);
    String girlname = ((TextView)findViewById(R.id.girl)).getText().toString();
    click.putExtra("girlname", girlname);

    startActivity(click);
}
public void noclick(View v){
    Intent click = new Intent(this, SecondActivity.class);

    String boyname = ((TextView)findViewById(R.id.boy)).getText().toString();
    click.putExtra("boyname", boyname);
    String girlname = ((TextView)findViewById(R.id.girl)).getText().toString();
    click.putExtra("girlname", girlname);

    startActivity(click);
}
}
```

SecondActivity java

```
package gr.com.plaza.stackoverflowquestion;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.content.Intent;

public class SecondActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

Second question = new Second();
private int likes = question.getlikes();
private int dislikes = question.getdislikes();
private int count = question.getcounter();

private boolean isbuttonclicked = false;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_second);

    Bundle mainactivitydata = getIntent().getExtras();

    String boyname = mainactivitydata.getString("boyname");
    TextView boynamesecond = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.boysecond);
    boynamesecond.setText(boyname);
    String girlname = mainactivitydata.getString("girlname");
    TextView girlnamesecond = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.girlsecond);
    girlnamesecond.setText(girlname);

    Button like = (Button)findViewById(R.id.like);
    Button dislike = (Button)findViewById(R.id.dislike);

    like.setOnClickListener(
            new Button.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    if (v.getId() == R.id.like) {
                        isbuttonclicked = !isbuttonclicked;
                        TextView like = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.like);

                        like.setText(count+"  " + likes++);
                    }
                }
            }
    );
    dislike.setOnClickListener(
            new Button.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    if (v.getId() == R.id.like) {
                        isbuttonclicked = !isbuttonclicked;
                        TextView dislike = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.dislike);

                        dislike.setText(count+"  " + dislikes++);
                    }
                }
            }
    );
}
public void answeredclick(View v){
    Intent click = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
    startActivity(click);
}

}
```

MainActivity xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context="gr.com.plaza.stackoverflowquestion.MainActivity"
android:id="@+id/main">

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:text="@string/boyname"
    android:id="@+id/boy"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="61dp" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:text="@string/girlname"
    android:id="@+id/girl"
    android:layout_below="@+id/boy"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="49dp" />

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/yesbutton"
    android:id="@+id/yes"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:onClick="yesclick" />

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/nobutton"
    android:id="@+id/no"
    android:layout_below="@+id/yes"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="39dp"
    android:onClick="noclick" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

SecondActivity xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context="gr.com.plaza.stackoverflowquestion.SecondActivity">

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:text="@string/boyname"
    android:id="@+id/boysecond"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="61dp" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:text="@string/girlname"
    android:id="@+id/girlsecond"
    android:layout_below="@+id/boysecond"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="49dp" />

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/answered"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:onClick="answeredclick" />


<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/likebutton"
    android:id="@+id/like"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/dislikebutton"
    android:id="@+id/dislike"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/like"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Second java

```
package gr.com.plaza.stackoverflowquestion;

import java.util.Random;

public class Second {


    private String[] boyname = new String[]{
            "George",
            "Jim",
            "Mike"
    };
    private String[] girlname = new String[]{
            "Mary",
            "Helen",
            "Julia"
    };
    private int[] likes = new int[]{
            0,
            1,
            2
    };
    private int[] dislikes = new int[]{
            3,
            4,
            5
    };
    private int[] counter = new int[]{
            6,
            7,
            8
    };

    public int randomindex = new Random().nextInt(boyname.length);

    private String[] name = new String[]{
            boyname[randomindex],
            girlname[randomindex]
    };
    private int[] likability = new int[]{
            likes[randomindex],
            dislikes[randomindex],
            counter[randomindex]
    };
    public String getboyname() {
            return name[0];
    }

    public String getgirlname() {
            return name[1];
    }

    public int getlikes() {
            return likability[0];
    }

    public int getdislikes() {
            return likability[1];
    }

    public int getcounter() {
            return likability[2];
    }
}
```

and AndroidManifest xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="gr.com.plaza.stackoverflowquestion">

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".SecondActivity"></activity>
</application>

</manifest>
```

sorry for the long post but I'm desperate

the only thing I've thought so far is a boolean that will make random generate a new number only if it is true but i don't know if that would work and also i'm not sure how to do it either.
I want to thank everyone in advance

EXAMPLE
On create Random generates an index for my arrays in Second.class
Say it generated 1
Then on screen it shows the names that have index 1 in the String array
Jim, Helen
Then you press yes or no
The like and dislike buttons appear
But when you press like or dislike Random generates a new number and shows the number on the screen but I want it to show on screen the number that it generated the first time and not generate a new one

Comment: Shorten your code and show exactly on which line you want to achieve something.

Comment: Can you please explain again what you want to achieve? Maybe by an example?

Comment: Last time I posted a shortened code and someone asked me to post the whole code so he could run the app, so i deleted the post and created this one. I'll add an example now

Comment: Added an example. I don't have the rep to post images yet